# center text vertically and remove margin under text

Tags: css, css-float

I have 3 divs, an image div, a text div and another image div

http://jsfiddle.net/m02pw4wk/4/

```
<div id="1" style="display:inline-block; width:100px">
    <span style="margin:0;">Center<span>
</div>
```

I want to center the span text in its parent div

I tried vertical-align on the text but no success, also I see that there is a small margin, ou padding below the text, where is it coming from ?

Any pointing on the solution would be helpful

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `vertical-align` property for the `img` element - not the text. It's worth noting that the default value for this property is `baseline`, thus the image element is aligned to the baseline of the text. Values such as `top`/`bottom`/`middle` will change this behavior.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hv27wbLg/)

```
img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

It's also worth noting that `id`s are suppose to be unique.

Comment: Thanks alot Josh, I am trying to understand, why do you apply the style vertical-align to the image and not the text ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="userbox" style="float:right; background-color:grey;display:table;">

    <div id="1" style="display:inline-block">
        <img src="http://www.dev2one.com/excel2web/demo/images/user_pic2.png" />

    </div>

    <div id="1" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
        <span style="margin:0;">Center<span>
    </div>

    <div id="1" style="display:inline-block">
        <img src="http://www.dev2one.com/excel2web/demo/images/cross.png" />

    </div>

</div>
```